# Can't click button on Button in PopupWindow

Tags: android, button, click, popupwindow

When i show a PopupWindow which contain Button I can't click him. Performs the onclick, but does not change the graphics.

It shows PopupWindow:

```
public void btn_friendsgame_newClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
            (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

    RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.layout_content);



    Button b = new Button(this); // THIS BUTTON CAN'T CLICK!



    b.setText("Test");
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    content.addView(b);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
               LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    Button close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_settings);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

custom_dialog.xml: http://pastebin.com/dLivuE17

How to repair this?

Comment: Is this an `AlertDialog` box? or what kind of popup? Why not use the alert dialog builder which contains up to three buttons that you can code.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't attaching him to an `onClickListener` as you do with your `close` button. I don't know what you want `b` to do so I can't give you any code but you obviously know how to attach an `onClick` event to a button since you already have with `close`. Do the same thing with `b` and put whatever logic you need inside the `onClick()` and you should be able to click him.

```
public void btn_friendsgame_newClick(View v) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
            (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

    RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.layout_content);



    Button b = new Button(this); // THIS BUTTON CAN'T CLICK!



    b.setText("Test");
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    content.addView(b);

   // here set onClick
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // put logic in here to do whatever you want
      }


    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
               LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(this.findViewById(R.id.main), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    Button close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_settings);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, no.
Button close which is loading from XML works good. It has custom graphic.
But Button b which is created programmatically can't click - When I click him, him graphic doesn't change. Generally Button b is for test.

Comment: I know. That's what my answer relates to. You haven't set an `onClick()` for it as you did for `close` which is why you can click on `close` but not `b`. You need to assign an `onClick()` for `b` so it knows to listen for the `click` event and knows what to do when it is clicked. You put your logic of changing graphic or whatever you want inside the `onClick()` of `b`